# Which RDKit fingerprint corresponds to the ECFP4 fingerprint

Tags: rdkit

I do have two questions about the Morgan fingerprint function of RDKit.
I couldn't figure out whether a Morgan fingerprint with the radius 2 or 4 corresponds to the ECFP4.
Furthermore I couldn't figure out, why the calculated similarity between two molecules differs substantially (much smaller) when using `GetMorganFingerprintAsBitVect(nBits=2048)` instead of `GetMorganFingerprint`?
Help or explanations would be very much appreciated.
Kind regards
Philipp

Comment: Please provide more details about your second question. What commands did you run? What were the outputs? How did you calculate the similarities, etc.

Answer (score 2):

In answer to your first question, according to https://www.rdkit.org/docs/GettingStartedInPython.html, a radius of 2 is roughly equivalent to ecfp4.

> The default atom invariants use connectivity information similar to
> those used for the well known ECFP family of fingerprints.
> Feature-based invariants, similar to those used for the FCFP
> fingerprints, can also be used. The feature definitions used are
> defined in the section Feature Definitions Used in the Morgan
> Fingerprints. At times this can lead to quite different similarity
> scores:
>
> ```
> m1 = Chem.MolFromSmiles('c1ccccn1')
> m2 = Chem.MolFromSmiles('c1ccco1')
> fp1 = AllChem.GetMorganFingerprint(m1,2)
> fp2 = AllChem.GetMorganFingerprint(m2,2)
> ffp1 = AllChem.GetMorganFingerprint(m1,2,useFeatures=True)
> ffp2 = AllChem.GetMorganFingerprint(m2,2,useFeatures=True)
> DataStructs.DiceSimilarity(fp1,fp2)
> 0.36...
> DataStructs.DiceSimilarity(ffp1,ffp2)
> 0.90...
> ```
>
> When comparing the ECFP/FCFP fingerprints and the Morgan fingerprints generated by the RDKit, remember that the 4 in ECFP4
> corresponds to the diameter of the atom environments considered, while
> the Morgan fingerprints take a radius parameter. So the examples
> above, with radius=2, are roughly equivalent to ECFP4 and FCFP4.